# How To Get DataTable In All Events OF GridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a gridview in my form.FirstTime in pageload iam loading gridview by calling function "FillgridFileExpenses()".

```
Sub FillgridFileExpenses()
        If txtInvFileNo.Text = String.Empty Then
            objinvoiceT.intfileID = 0
        Else
            objinvoiceT.intfileID = Convert.ToInt32(txtInvFileNo.Text)
        End If
        temptab1 = objinvoiceT.selFileExpensesView()
        temptab1.Columns.Add("AllInRate")
    If (temptab1.Rows.Count > 0) Then
        GridViewInvoiceT.DataSource = temptab1
        dtInvoice = temptab1
        'dtInvoice.Columns.Add("AllInRate")
        GridViewInvoiceT.DataBind()
        GridViewInvoiceT.Columns.Item(10).Visible = True
    Else
        temptab1.Rows.Add(temptab1.NewRow())
        GridViewInvoiceT.DataSource = temptab1
        dtInvoice = temptab1
        GridViewInvoiceT.DataBind()
        Dim TotalColumns As Integer
        TotalColumns = GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(0).Cells.Count
        GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(0).Cells.Clear()
        GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(0).Cells.Add(New TableCell())
        GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(0).Cells(0).ColumnSpan = TotalColumns
        If txtInvFileNo.Text = String.Empty Then
            GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text = "No Record Found, Must Select a File Number "
        Else
            GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text = "No Record Found For File Number : " + " " + txtInvFileNo.Text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In the above code iam using a datatable called dtInvoice.Whatever changes iam making in gridview events such as deleting or updating or adding a new row,all these should reflect in dtInvoice and not in database.Iam getting dtInvoice in updating event ,but in deleting 
dtInvoice is coming with no rows and getting an error.Following is my code for updating and deleting

```
Protected Sub GridViewInvoiceT_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridViewInvoiceT.RowUpdating
    cmbChargeName = CType(GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("cmbChargeName"), DropDownList)
    cmbInvCurency = CType(GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("cmbInvCurency"), DropDownList)
    txtInvoiceNo1 = CType(GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtInvoiceNo1"), TextBox)
    txtInvoiceDate1 = CType(GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtInvoiceDate1"), TextBox)
    txtInvAmount1 = CType(GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtInvAmount1"), TextBox)
    txtInvExRate1 = CType(GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtInvExRate1"), TextBox)
    txtInvRemarks1 = CType(GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtInvRemarks1"), TextBox)
    cmbAllinRight = CType(GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddAllInRate"), DropDownList)
    Dim lblAllInRate As Label = CType(GridViewInvoiceT.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lblAllInRate"), Label)
    objinvoiceT.intfileID = Convert.ToInt32(txtInvFileNo.Text)
     dtInvoice.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("AllInRate") = cmbAllinRight.SelectedItem
    dtInvoice.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("ChargeName") = cmbChargeName.SelectedItem
    dtInvoice.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("InvoiceNo") = txtInvoiceNo1.Text
    If txtInvoiceDate1.Text = String.Empty Then
        dtInvoice.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("InvoiceDate") = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1800")
    Else
        dtInvoice.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("InvoiceDate") = Convert.ToDateTime(txtInvoiceDate1.Text)
    End If
    dtInvoice.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("Currency") = cmbInvCurency.SelectedItem
    dtInvoice.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("InvAmount") = txtInvAmount1.Text
    dtInvoice.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("InvExRate") = txtInvExRate1.Text
    dtInvoice.Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("InvRemarks") = txtInvRemarks1.Text
    GridViewInvoiceT.EditIndex = -1
    GridViewInvoiceT.DataSource = dtInvoice
    GridViewInvoiceT.DataBind()
    FillInvoice()

End Sub

Protected Sub GridViewInvoiceT_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridViewInvoiceT.RowDeleting
          dtInvoice.Rows.Remove(GridViewInvoiceT.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)
    GridViewInvoiceT.DataSource = dtInvoice
    GridViewInvoiceT.DataBind()
End Sub
```

End Sub
    Sub FillInvoice()

```
    GridViewInvoiceT.DataSource = dtInvoice
    GridViewInvoiceT.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Can anyone help to get dtInvoice with reflectedchanges that i made in updating in deleting?

Answer (score 1):

In your GridViewInvoiceT_RowDeleting method, change;

```
dtInvoice.Rows.Remove(GridViewInvoiceT.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)
```

to use the 'Delete' method on the DataRow.

Remove - removes the row for the datatable, causing you data provider not to notice the row anymore. By using delete, you are **marking** the row to be deleted, hence your provider code will notice the delete, and request the row to be deleted from the database.